# Set expires for all static data, except home url

Tags: nginx, cache

I am creating a spa website, now for the static data (javascript) I wish to set up the headers in such a way it only expires after a certain amount of time.

However to allow for easy updating I wish to *not* do this on the main page. (Each new version will rename the bundled javascript, so cache will be invalidated that way).

My site data has the following snippet:

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass  http://${DYNAMIC_SERVER}:${DYNAMIC_PORT};
}

location / {
    # redirect everything to show the main SPA application
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    expires 7d;
}
```

This caches *everything*, including `index.html` - how do I prevent this?

Comment: Try adding: `location = /index.html { }`

Comment: Well the "idea" of a spa is that anything is "redirected" to index.html file - so any location that is not directly found by try_files *will* serve index.html: only at file level the expires should be handled.

Comment: I believe @RichardSmith meant adding `location = / { }` block.

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu not really, the `try_files` statement will internally rewrite the request to `/index.html`, which causes Nginx to restart the search for a `location` to process the request. The `expires` is calculated from the final `location` that processes the request. So if the URI `/any/route` does not correspond to a local file, it will be handled by the `location = /index.html` block. But is that what the OP wants?

Comment: BTW, if you want to only affect the URI `/`, then use: `location = / { try_files /index.html =404; }`

Comment: @RichardSmith I feel I am misunderstanding it - can you elaborate for a full answer? I wish to redirect anything (Ie `site`, `site/data` and `site/blah`) to index.html, except things for which a file actually exist (like `site/favicon.ico` and `site/robots.txt` and `site/js-bundle-13423.js`)

Comment: @paul23 I understand that part. What is not clear is which of `site`, `site/data` and `site/blah` should have their `expires` set to zero.

Comment: @RichardSmith all of them - since they all point to index.html. Only `site/robots.txt` and `site/favicon.ico` and `site/js-bundle-13423.js` should have expires "set".

Comment: And adding `location = /index.html { }` didn't work?

Comment: @RichardSmith I can accept that if it's in an answer. - And an explanation of why it will work (for me it looks like it would only work when using `sites/index.html` directly) would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable cache on any URI that **does not** resolve to a static file, but is instead, *internally rewritten* to `/index.html`, you will need to add a separate `location` block to process that one URI.

For example:

```
location / {
    expires 7d;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
location = /index.html {
    expires -1;
}
```

Nginx selects a `location` block to process the original requested URI. The `try_files` statement causes that URI to be *internally rewritten* if it does not match a static file or directory. Nginx then restarts the search for a `location` block to process the rewritten URI.